# 5 star rating using CakeDC plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, rating, cakedc

I am using CakeDC ratings to make a star rating in my site. I managed to make it work but it is displaying radio choices. I really wanted it to be a 5-star like functionality. In their documentation they tell that it is possible to use Jquery.ui.stars to make it work, but I think I will spend a lot of time trying to.

Does anyone know or have a sample code (php, script, css and html) that make this functionality using that Ratings plugin?

Comment: I use https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty for rating stuff. Combining this with some php is pretty straight forward ;)

Comment: The CakePHP ratings plugin sucks. Definitely try what @Jelmer suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did see the js/css folders in webroot, right?
https://github.com/CakeDC/ratings/tree/master/webroot

They do serve a higher purpose. What you want is actually already part of the plugin and automatically enabled if you include the stylesheet and the javascript file...

So, just include the scripts + jquery. Done. Whats the issue?

Comment: Well. I just see radios everywhere... I added the plugin this way: `.$this->Rating->display(array(
        'item' => $article['Article']['id'],
        'type' => 'radio',
        'stars' => 5,
        'value' => $article['Article']['rating'],
        'createForm' => array('url' => array_merge($this->passedArgs, array('rate' => $article['Article']['id'], 'redirect' => true)))),array('style' =>'float:left',
        ))` The css and js are in the right place...

Comment: It internally renders `starForm()`, so it usually does display the stars. Debug your code using Firefox+Firebug. This will reveal your JS issues.

Comment: Thank you... I will do it and I tell you the results.

Comment: Hi. I managed to do that works. I had some minor problems such as wrong path to js and css. But the most important was that I was not using the js to stylize: 
`$('#ratingform').stars({
    split:2,
    cancelShow:false,
    callback: function(ui, type, value) {
        ui.$form.submit();
    }
});`